# jQuery callback is firing twice

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I have a very basic jQuery get method asking the server for a specific bit of data. Problem is the callback is firing twice which is messing with some code further down the line. I have put some console logs all around to figure out exactly where the duplication was occurring and it's definitely the callback. Here's a simplified version of what's going on:

```
doThing: ->
 console.log 'This only happens once...'
  $.get("/patrons/get_patron_code").done((transport) =>
    console.log 'This happens twice!'
    @sendToServer(object_with_properties_set_as_transport)

sendToServer: (object) ->
  console.log 'So now this gets sent twice which causes errors server side.'
```

I'm creating a workaround for this but now I've added extra lines and my code looks messy. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Also I have found that if I don't use a function within the done method the code only runs once but of course this does me no good since I need that transport data.

Comment: what is the callback bound to? Is the event bubbling up?

Comment: I'm going to be honest, I'm not as well versed with javascript as I should be so I'm not really sure. Is there an easy way to figure that out?

Comment: well, at the very least you'd need a closing parenthesis at the end of  the call to `@sendToServer` since you wrap done. But that might be your issue as well. try `done (transport)`